# special character in itextSharp C#

Tags: c#, itext

I'm working on pdf document where I have to include some special characters in cell phrases, I tried to search relevant result but did not found any
The character is [image] a +- sign. additionally square, cube sign as well.

Here is my code snippet

```
public Font calibri_7 = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 7, Font.NORMAL);
PdfPCell cb21 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("50+/-25", calibri_7));
```

What changes I need to do in order to get it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place that character in your pdf you should use the unicode character escape: \u2213. If you want to know about other special character unicode notations, then I would like to suggest the next resource: https://charbase.com/block/mathematical-operators

Your code should then be modified to the following:

```
PdfPCell cb21 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\u00B1", calibri_7));
```

[image]

Comment: In what way doesn't it work, @T.Giri? To clarify that the unicode notation works, i've added a screenshot.

Comment: sorry i checked the wrong pdf and said it worked before, i tried Unicode but not work

Comment: i'm using it itextsharp pdf generation, unicode word directly but when i include it into cell phrases it gives empty

Comment: @T.Giri I've solved the issue and found the correct unicode notation: \u00B1. This works